# how can i fix this? Could not find a file named

Tags: flutter

Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\flutter\flutter_windows_3.3.3-stable\flutter.pub-cache\git\video_thumbnail-6721fbd48f9c2c15fa4c6c824c648088e6026475".
pub get failed (66; Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\flutter\flutter_windows_3.3.3-stable\flutter.pub-cache\git\video_thumbnail-6721fbd48f9c2c15fa4c6c824c648088e6026475".)

Comment: Check youre folder location . The link must be wrong for sure . as far i know it cant end on a .pub or.  :)

Comment: When do you get this error eg. are you in your  project's folder?

Comment: Please run "flutter doctor" and make sure everything looks good before proceeding.